# MongoDB changes the DateTime on insert

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have an object that looks as follows just before being inserted into MongoDB:

[image]

But after being inserted:

```
await context.MyCollectionName.InsertOneAsync(thresholdReport);
```

it looks like this in MongoDB:

[image]

Seems like the database changes the DateTime to UTC(?). How can I force it to insert the document as it is?

Comment: Perhaps you could add the timezone when you set the DateTime?  BTW, I think both DateTimes are the same, in Norway.

Comment: Is it the time provided by the ObjectID ? If yes, you could manage to modify it each and every time there's a modification.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille it is 1 hour ahead of UTC in Norway now.

Comment: I know that.  Do you agee that the time that MongoDB reports is equal to the one you set?